# IIS returns 500 when Node app returns a 4xx

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, iisnode

I have also asked this on the [iisnode github project](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/325)

I am using IISNode via a Windows Azure Website.

If my Node app returns a 2xx status code (200, 201, etc), then all is well and works as expected.

if my Node app returns a 4xx status code, for example:
`response.send(404, "not found")` (I am using Restify) then I get a 500 sent to the client and the body is simply "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

If I do `azure site log tail <sitename>`, then when the 500 gets sent to the client, the log contains HTML of a 404.

```
...
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h3> 
<h4>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed,
or is temporarily unavailable.</h4> 
</div> 
...
```

I really just want IISNode/IIS to take my 404 and send it on down to the client. This is also true of 401s, 409s, etc. They all cause a 500 to get sent instead.

I have tried `<customErrors mode="off" />` and `<httpErrors existingResponse="passThrough" />` in my web.config to no avail. Here is my web.config now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>         
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <staticContent>
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
    </staticContent>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
           <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
           <match url="/*" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For what it's worth, I can't get IISnode to do anything but return 200s from my node app. Trying to get IIS to serve my static files, enable node-inspector, or really any of the more interesting IISNode features cause a 500 for me. No idea why, and would love to get past it!

## Similar StackOverflow Questions

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144405/windows-azure-websites-is-overriding-my-404-and-500-error-pages-in-my-node-js-ap) is pretty much *exactly* my problem. Except that `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` does not work for me. I feel like I have something more fundamentally wrong with my IISNode setup, so if anyone has any ideas on things to try I'm all ears.

Comment: I have an IISNode app running without the issue and the only major difference between my web.config and yours is I don't have the `<match url="/*" />` rule in the `DynamicContent`, does removing it change anything for you? I also don't have the `httpErrors` section.

Comment: I took out the match tag and that didn't change anything. I also tried creating a fresh website and deploying to that with the same results.

Comment: I have a handful of other things I plan to try this weekend. If I find a solution, I'll update here (and github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for some reason the following section in your config is causing this issue:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
</staticContent>
```

As a workaround, remove this section if possible and retry. I will investigate why this section is causing this issue.

Comment: I'll give this a shot tonight when I get home. Not sure what to do without those mimemaps though.

Comment: This does work, and I appear to no longer need `staticContent` anyway. I'm not sure why that is. But since everything is working, not going to question too much now :) Thanks Ranjith!

Answer (score 1):

As Ranjith pointed out, the `staticContent` section is the cause of the conflict. I just found you can limit those entries inside of `location` entries, so you can get all of IISNode as desired and still serve up static content. My web.config now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
           <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>

 <location path="public/fonts">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The added `location` entry at the end works around the 500 and static content conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exact same...500 error page returned from Azure/IIS. I used the web.config that Azure automatically generated as the basis, then added `<customErrors mode="off" />` and `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />`. I also removed the default staticContent node. Nothing is working.

Below is the web.config that I'm uploading to Azure. What in here is causing IIS/iisnode to return a 500 error page instead of the simple text error message I have node/express returning to the client?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the NodeInspector rule? I've never had any luck with that one.

Comment: Hi Erik, I tried your web.config along with the following server.js and I get the expected error code i.e 409 back.

Server.js:
----------------------------
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(409, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end('Hello, world!');
}).listen(process.env.PORT);  

--------------
If you could share a simple repro application, I will investigate further.

Comment: This did the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144405/windows-azure-websites-is-overriding-my-404-and-500-error-pages-in-my-node-js-ap

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="DynamicContent">
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. In node I'm using express to `res.send(400, 'this is my error');`. Azure/IIS is turning that into a standard IIS 500 error page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (IIS Node on Win Server 2012R2). So I did not get the target content in the body.

At the beginning I had response:

```
code: 400
body: Bad Request
```

Then I added `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` and I got response:

```
code: 500
body: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred
```

Then I have changed IIS Feature Delegation for "Error Pages" to "Read/Write" and this resolved my issue. Finally I had proper response:

```
code: 400
body: { "error": {...} }
```

I hope this helps.