# Node.js with Express 400 always returning Bad Request in body

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a simple request to my Node.js API. I am returning 400 as the status code and a custom message in the send method. For some odd reason all that is returned is a Bad Request text in the body not the custom message. Not sure what I am doing wrong. This works fine in development environment but not in staging environment.

Simply

```
res.status(400);
res;
res.send('You already are joined');
```

Comment: try this  `res.status(400).end('You already joined');`

Comment: @deolectrix that did not work. Still "Bad Request" in body.

Comment: Is the server behind any load-balancers/nginx?

Comment: No the server is being hosted by Azure.

Comment: What is your development environment where it works? What is different between the development and staging environments?

Comment: @DrCord development box is my local machine (Mac) and staging is a normal iis server. All 200 request works fine in both environments. Something about 400 not allowing custom messages.

Comment: I would examine the differences in your environments. The dev is a mac the other is a windows server...

Comment: iis requires a web.config file to run. The answer adding the following tag to your  config file. <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /> Answer is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144405/windows-azure-websites-is-overriding-my-404-and-500-error-pages-in-my-node-js-ap